# Fetching images from mongoDB using mongoose, nodeJS, express, react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I have been working off the following [guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/upload-and-retrieve-image-on-mongodb-using-mongoose/) to upload and fetch images to and from mongoDB and am having issues getting the images to redisplay on the react page after being fetched. I think the issue is with the HTML img src but it could be further up the line so ill walk through everything I have done.

server.js

```
// --------------------  Mongoose schema -------------------
var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    img:
    {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
});
const offeringSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: [imageSchema]
});
const Image = mongoose.model("Image", imageSchema)
const Offering = mongoose.model("Offering", offeringSchema);

// --------------------  Set up Multer -------------------
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/uploads/images',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() +
            path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

// --------------------  Post Offering Data -------------------
// upload featured offering image
app.post('/admin/OfferingFeatureImage', upload.single('featuredImage'), function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        if (req.user.userData[0].admin === true) {
            console.log(req.file);
            var newImage = new Image();
            newImage.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path)
            newImage.img.contentType = 'image/png';
            Offering.updateOne({ _id: req.body.offeringID }, {image:[newImage]}, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    res.redirect("/Admin/Offerings");
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.send("not-privileged")
        }
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login")
    };
});

// --------------------  Get Offering Data -------------------
app.get("/data/allInvestment", function (req, res) {
    Offering.find({}, function (err, foundOfferings) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(foundOfferings);
        };
    });
});
```

On the client side i am able to get the offering data and see the img data appears to be present

[client side data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os0QR.png)

```
{props.investmentsData.image[0] !== undefined &&
                    <img src={"data:" + props.investmentsData.image[0].img.contentType + ";base64," + props.investmentsData.image[0].img.data.toString('base64')} className="card-img-top" alt="..."></img>
                }
```

[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihywP.png)

Comment: I don’t know answer of your question, but usually images stored in file server and addrese of image stores in database

Comment: Im pretty new to this, would be open to that, any guides you could like would be helpful

Comment: Can you see what HTML is generated, see the link which is put in the HTML source code. And try to hit that link manually with browser URL input?